# Understanding R-syntax in the code for Bayesian Optimization

Tags: r

This is with reference to [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/263649/206718) on implementation of Bayesian Optimization. I am unable to understand the following R-code that defines a function xgb.cv.bayes(). The code is as follows:

```
xgb.cv.bayes <- function(max.depth, min_child_weight, subsample, colsample_bytree, gamma){
  cv <- xgv.cv(params = list(booster = 'gbtree', eta = 0.05,
                         max_depth = max.depth,
                         min_child_weight = min_child_weight,
                         subsample = subsample,
                         colsample_bytree = colsample_bytree,
                         gamma = gamma,
                         lambda = 1, alpha = 0,
                         objective = 'binary:logistic',
                         eval_metric = 'auc'),
             data = data.matrix(df.train[,-target.var]),
             label = as.matrix(df.train[, target.var]),
             nround = 500, folds = cv_folds, prediction = TRUE,
             showsd = TRUE, early.stop.round = 5, maximize = TRUE,
             verbose = 0
  )
  list(Score = cv$dt[, max(test.auc.mean)],
   Pred = cv$pred)
}
```

I am unable to understand the following part of code that comes after closing parenthesis of xgb.cv():

```
list(Score = cv$dt[, max(test.auc.mean)],
   Pred = cv$pred)
```

Or very briefly, I do not understand the following syntax:

```
xgb.cv.bayes <- function(max.depth, min_child_weight, subsample, colsample_bytree, gamma){
  cv <- xgv.cv(...)list(...)
}
```

I will be grateful in understanding this R-syntax and where can I find more examples of this.

Comment: Maybe read `?Extract`, `?list` and `?max`?

Comment: replace `cv$dt` with `cv$evaluation_log` and the function should work. Basically after running  `xgv.cv` you go through the results and output the `max(auc)` and the predictions on the cv folds.

Comment: The function works. There is no problem But I do not understand this syntax 'xgb.cv()list()'
Also I have seen ?Extract. It refers to square brackets. Here we have round brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R the value of the last expression in a function is automatically the return value of this function. So the function you presented has exactly two steps:

1. compute the result of `xgv.cv(...)` and store the result in a
   variable `cv`
2. create a list with two entries (`Score` and `Pred`)
   whose values are extracted from `cv`.

Since the expression that creates the list is the last expression in the function, the list is automatically the return value. So, if you would execute `test <- xgb.cv.bayes(...)` you could then access `test$Score` and `test$Pred`. 
Does this answer your question?

Comment: It does answer my question. Thank you for your time and explanation. May I please know any reference where this kind of syntax is explained in a little more detail and what is the syntax called. There is a similar syntax in python but it works differently, the last expression is input to the function. (And incidentally, I am unable to upvote you because of my reputation score.)

Comment: You're welcome! I really like the book "Advanced R" by Hadley Wickham. There are also large parts available online, e.g. you may find http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html useful. (Especially the section "return values")